# Assets: problems assigning images. Call to a member function file_id() on a non-object

Tags: assets, channel-images

Call to a member function file_id() on a non-object in /(path to my system folder)/expressionengine/third_party/assets/views/thumbview/files.php on line 15

I get the above error message when I post my channel entry.

Comment: There seems to be an incompatibility with the bw_required_category extension. If I correctly assign the category, the channel entry gets posted without problems.

Comment: See answer here: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/4902/betterworkflow-preview-throws-php-security-warnings/4932#4932

Answer (score 1):

Just a final follow-up - this has been fixed in the latest versions of Assets.